# Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user with Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile for a SQL Server database that looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ARG SA_PASSWORD
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=$SA_PASSWORD
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433 

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./ /scripts/

EXPOSE 1433 

RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" &&  (for foo in /scripts/*.sql;do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -P${SA_PASSWORD}  -i$foo;done)
```

When I run docker build I get the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'.

This Dockerfile has worked before and I can't remember making any changes before it stopped working. I have tried reinstalling Docker and removing all containers and images.

Any ideas what could be the wrong?

Comment: What is your docker build command?

Comment: docker build -t database . I have tried with both --build-args and manually setting the password in the Dockerfile. I suspect it has something to do with the type of authorization it is making (SQL server vs Windows authentication).

Comment: Does your pw match these requirements: A strong system administrator (SA) password: At least 8 characters including uppercase, lowercase letters, base-10 digits and/or non-alphanumeric symbols. ? Or does it include special characters which might interact with bash? Try to run sqlcmd from outside via docker exec

Comment: Yes, like I said the Dockerfile has worked before with these exact settings and the same password. I can't run docker exec because the container does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the server isn't ready right after the message "Service Broker manager has started".

You'll need some delay like that:

```
RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && sleep 5s &&  (for foo in /scripts/*.sql;do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -P${SA_PASSWORD}  -i$foo;done)
```

It might be better to run a script that waits for the sqlserver like that:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ARG SA_PASSWORD
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=$SA_PASSWORD
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433 

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./ /scripts/
RUN chmod +x /scripts/configure-db.sh

EXPOSE 1433 

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & /scripts/configure-db.sh
```

> configure-db.sh
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # wait for MSSQL server to start
> export STATUS=1
> i=0
>
> while [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]] && [[ $i -lt 300 ]]; do
>   i=$i+1
>   /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -t 1 -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "select 1" >> /dev/null
>   STATUS=$?
> done
>
> if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then 
>   echo "Error: MSSQL SERVER took more than 60 seconds to start up."
>   echo $SA_PASSWORD
>   exit 1
> fi
>
> echo "======= MSSQL SERVER STARTED ========" | tee -a /scripts/config.log
> # Run the setup script to create the DB and the schema in the DB
> #/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Abcdefg1234 -d master -i /scripts/test.sql
> for foo in /scripts/*.sql;
> do
>   /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -P${SA_PASSWORD}  -i$foo;
> done
>
> echo "======= MSSQL CONFIG COMPLETE =======" | tee -a /scripts/config.log
> ```

script code from: https://github.com/mcmoe/mssqldocker/blob/master/configure-db.sh